# Playing a sound in a browser (Chrome), from javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

I am writing an html page. I want it to make sounds, as specified by some javascript as it runs.

In the html, as recommended in the answers I have read here, I have the line

```
<embed src="wavs/beep.wav" autostart="true" width="0" height="0" id="beep" 
  enablejavascript="true">
```

This plays the sound at load time, so I am confident I have given a valid path to a valid .wav file. (I will set autostart to false once everything is working.)

I have a function

```
function playSound ( soundname )   
  {
    var thissound = document.getElementById( soundname );
    thissound.Play();
    alert( "Played " + soundname );
  }
```

which I call using

```
  playSound( "beep" );
```

But when that call is made, there is no sound, although the alert happens. It looks to me as if I am doing everything in the recommended way, but I must have got something wrong.  What should I check next?

Answer (score 30):

**Use the native HTML5 Audio API**

In Chrome's console try creating a new instance of the Audio element, passing in the path of the sound you want to buffer. For example, if we want a typewriter sound we can do something like:

```js
const typeWriter = new Audio("https://www.freesound.org/data/previews/256/256458_4772965-lq.mp3");
```

*Note: for this exact sound to buffer and avoid a CSRF issue, you must be working in a console at [www.freesound.org](http://www.freesound.org)*

`typeWriter` now represents an html audio tag.

Try making the sound loop by setting `typeWriter.loop = true`

Finally, play/pause the sound with `typeWriter.play()` & `typeWriter.pause()`

Comment: @user36956 should have marked this as the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Have tried this code, and it works well in most browsers
used the js method below

```
function playSound(soundfile_ogg, soundfile_mp, soundfile_ma) {
    if ("Audio" in window) {
        var a = new Audio();
        if (!!(a.canPlayType && a.canPlayType('audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"')
                .replace(/no/, '')))
            a.src = soundfile_ogg;
        else if (!!(a.canPlayType && a.canPlayType('audio/mpeg;').replace(/no/,
                '')))
            a.src = soundfile_mp;
        else if (!!(a.canPlayType && a.canPlayType(
                'audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"').replace(/no/, '')))
            a.src = soundfile_ma;
        else
            a.src = soundfile_mp;

        a.autoplay = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error because the getElementById gives you an embed element and not an audio element. embed element does not know how to play. In other words, there is no play method in embed element. Use the following code to play it properly.

```
<html>
<script>
function playSound ( soundname )
  {
    var thissound = document.getElementById( soundname );
    thissound.play();
    alert( "Played " + soundname );
  }
</script>
<body>
  <audio src="wavs/beep.wav" id="beep" autostart="false"></audio>
  <input type=button onclick="playSound('beep')">play</input>
  </body>
  </html>
```

One more note. Depending on the browsers you might want to support, you need multiple versions of the audio sources defined. Refer to [this](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/html/article.php/3920991/HTML5-Primer-How-To-Use-the-Audio-Tag.htm) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be .play() - with a lowercase 'p'?

Depending on what browsers you want to support, you might want to consider replacing your `<embed>` with an HTML5 `<audio>` tag: http://www.storiesinflight.com/html5/audio.html. This page has some working js examples as well!

Comment: Thanks, you are right.  .Play() just does nothing, and I get the alert but no sound.  .play() actually fails, so I don't get the alert.

Comment: See Crushers comment below: the js should work when you would use the audio element!