# How to make an alert window also play a sound

Tags: google-chrome, alert

I can easily make an alert on a website using:

```
alert("Hello. I am a an alert window");
```

But how do I also make it beep or play a sound when it displays? I know it's usually bad practice but the person I'm designing for has bad eyesight and needs an audio cue. The person is using Chrome on a laptop. It would be even better if anyone knew of a setting in Chrome that could do this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers here probably help you:
[Playing a sound in a browser (Chrome), from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739888/playing-a-sound-in-a-browser-chrome-from-javascript)

Besides that, I would create a function like this and call it instead of the native alert function:

```
function customAlert(message) {
    alert(message);
    playAlertSound(); // Implemented by you somewhere else.
}
```

Also I am pretty sure the user needs to interact with the website, before the browser allows you to play sound. (Clicking on anything counts as interaction.)

Comment: Thank you. The answers in the link you supplied resolved my issue.